# ValueError: unsupported format character ')' (0x29) at index 21

Tags: python

I got the code from [Automate The Boring Stuff With Python](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter10/).

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format=' %(asctime)s(levelname)s- %(message)s')
logging.debug('Start of program')

def factorial(n):
    logging.debug('Start of factorial( %)' % (n))
    total = 1
    for i in range(n + 1):
        total *= i
        logging.debug('i is ' + str(i) + ', total is ' + str(total))
    logging.debug('End of factorial( %)' % (n))
    return total

print (factorial(5))
logging.debug('End of program')
```

When I run the code, the following error occurs:

> 2015-06-18 12:51:47,073 - DEBUG- Start of program
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/home/raqeeb.alam/PycharmProjects/E_mail/sub_links.py", line 14, in 
>        print factorial(5)
>        File "/home/raqeeb.alam/PycharmProjects/E_mail/sub_links.py", line 6, in factorial
>       logging.debug('Start of factorial( %)' % (n))
>       ValueError: unsupported format character ')' (0x29) at index 21

For these lines:

```
print (factorial(5))
logging.debug('End of program')
```

Comment: In addition to the answers below for making the python correct, you'll want to change `range(n+1)` to `range(1,n+1)` in order to get a non-zero answer.

Answer (score 3):

Should be:

```
logging.debug('Start of factorial(%s)' % (n))
...
logging.debug('End of factorial(%s)' % (n))
```

BTW: parentheses are redundant here. Could be simply:

```
logging.debug('Start of factorial(%s)' % n)
...
logging.debug('End of factorial(%s)' % n)
```

And `' %(asctime)s(levelname)s- %(message)s'` should be `' %(asctime)s%(levelname)s- %(message)s'`

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a `%` sign:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format=' %(asctime)s%(levelname)s- %(message)s')
#                                                            ^ HERE
```

Answer (score 2):

```
logging.debug('Start of factorial( %)' % (n))
logging.debug('End of factorial( %)' % (n))
```

Those two lines should be

```
logging.debug('Start of factorial(%s)' % (n))
logging.debug('End of factorial(%s)' % (n))
```

Comment: Actually, when logging it is better practice to not do the string substitution directly: so it should be `logging.debug('Start of factorial(%s)', n)` - that way the operation will only be done if the message is actually logged according to the level in effect.

Answer (score 0):

This is a generally unsupported error. Try this:

It looks like Python is interpreting the % as a printf-like format character. Try using %%

means:

```
 logging.debug('Start of factorial( %%)' % (n))
```

.

.

.

```
 logging.debug('End of factorial( %%)' % (n))
```

To have more clean code try to remove () around n.

means:

```
 logging.debug('Start of factorial( %%)' % n)
```

.

.

.

```
 logging.debug('End of factorial( %%)' % n)
```